# SendRedirect at autoLogin

Tags: liferay, autologin

AutoLogin. The following exception occurs when trying to redirect to my custom portlet when user does not exist.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLImpl.generateToString(PortletURLImpl.java:850)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLImpl$ToStringPrivilegedAction.run(PortletURLImpl.java:1501)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLImpl$ToStringPrivilegedAction.run(PortletURLImpl.java:1)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil$NoPACL.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.security.lang.DoPrivilegedUtil.wrap(DoPrivilegedUtil.java:26)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLImpl.toString(PortletURLImpl.java:740)
```

when trying to call this

```
PortletURL portletURL = getRenderURL(request, somePortletName, somePlid);
response.sendRedirect(portletURL.toString());

public static PortletURL getRenderURL(HttpServletRequest request, String portletId, long plid)
{
    return PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(

            request,
            portletId,
            plid,
            PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
}
```

Is it forbidden to call sendRedirect in autologin or can You suggest me a workarround? story: after singleSignOn, if the user does not exists in liferay, it redirects him to my custom registration form and pre-fill retrieved known data.

Comment: It seems your `portletURL` is null, can you provide the code to `getrenderURL` method..

Comment: sorry, I have updated the code above